# Почему не работает класс form-control-sm?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Charges</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="checkbox">
        {foreach from=$charges_list item=item}
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="{$item.id}" data-amount="{$item.amount}" class="form-check-input" />
                    <input type="text" name="charge_amount[{$item.id}]" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    {$item.value}
                </div>
            </div>

        {/foreach}
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Хочу сделать маленький `input`.

Comment: а как он работать должен?

Comment: хочу сделать маленький инпут

Comment: вам нужен класс `input-sm`. Замените `form-control-sm` на `input-sm`

Comment: Спасибо) Заработало) Хотя в документации было так:  <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="smFormGroupInput" placeholder="you@example.com">
      </div>

Answer (score 3):

Потому что упомянутый класс упоминается в [Bootstrap 4-ой версии](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/), который сейчас в активной разработке и не вышел из alpha-версии.

Вы же подключаете, скорее всего, Bootstrap 3-ей версии, в котором класс называется
`.input-sm`, а не `.form-control-sm`.

Вот пример с подключенной 4-ой версией и вашим классом:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="lgFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg"><small>Обычный input</small></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="you@example.com">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm"><small>Мелкий input</small></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="smFormGroupInput" placeholder="you@example.com">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так: `form-control input-sm`

```
<input type="text" name="charge_amount[{$item.id}]" class="form-control input-sm" />
```